# Meteor setinterval too fast

Tags: javascript, timer, meteor

I have multiple countdown timers in my app and I'm updating those values using setInterval function. The idea of following code block is the loop through all ongoing games and update countdown clocks. I have 1000ms interval but it loops much faster than that. Why? When I open multiple browser windows to see countdown timer updates I can notice that interval is something like 500ms.

```
if (Meteor.isClient) {

    Meteor.setInterval(
        function() {

            var going = Games.find({isGoing: true});
            var goingFetch = going.fetch();
            var goingCount = going.count();

            for (i = 0; i < goingCount; i++) {
                Games.update(goingFetch[i]._id, {$set: {timeLeft: goingFetch[i].timeLeft - 1}});
            }               
        }
    , 1000 );
}
```

Is there better way to solve this problem? I may have 100 games simultaneously and every game have one to many timers. Timer type can be countdown or incremental and all timers are stoppable. Interval is always and in all cases 1000ms.

UPDATE
I did more tests and setInterval works fine but clients still have too fast countdown timer.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure your code isn't executed twice by mistake? Does `goingCount` produce correct results, for instance? `setInterval` isn't as accurate as `setTimeout`, but it shouldn't cause problems at 1000ms. Can we see more of your code?

Comment: I did more tests and setInterval works fine. It looks like the problem is somewhere else.